# Application With Multiple Activities and Single Launcher

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an application which has multiple activities associated with it. When the user clicks on the launcher icon I want the last used activity of the application to be shown.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well Gordon .. What I feel ... take one variable and store its value in Sharedprefrences. On launching your application, read the value of variable from sharedprefrences and invoke the activity as per variable.

Then before exiting the appication put this variable's value again in sharedprefrences for that particular actvity.

Thanks